# MVP spawning MVP of subcomponent

Tags: instantiation, mvp

I am having a big component. We could also assume it to be the main component. This component should contain a subcomponent which is an abstract panel in my case and it has its own MVP already implemented. Now I am implementing the MainComponent and therefore I need to spawn the MVP of the small reusable abstract subcomponent.

My question is now:
Where should I spawn each of the 3 subparts?
View in view and presenter +  model in the model?
View in view, presenter in presenter, model in model?

Thanks in advance for your opinions on this!

[image: MVP (with passive View)]

Comment: "I am having a big component." - that's because your name is Thor!

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail on your specific implementation of MVP but here are my thoughts on the subject:

> it has its own MVP already implemented

I am assuming this means that when a view is loaded (be it a main view or a sub view) it has already been wired up with the correct presenter and model. I am also assuming that if any of the sub-presenters share components or services with the main presenter these are resolved by a dependency injection framework.

If my assumption is incorrect then the component that is responsible for loading your views should be updated to ensure this happens i.e. when a view is loaded it is functional.

> My question is now: Where should I spawn each of the 3 subparts? View
>   in view and presenter + model in the model? View in view, presenter in
>   presenter, model in model?

As per my comment above, you should have an object that is responsible for loading views and ensuring that they are correctly configured (lets call this object the `ViewLoader`). This object should only be invoked directly from your view layer i.e. never called from a presenter.

The problem with this though is that presenter objects drive the application so require a way of telling the view layer to load another view. You can solve this problem by passing a view reference to the presenter. The view reference should be hidden behind an interface that does not expose any details about the view technology being used, for example:

```
public interface IMainView
{
    void OpenSettings();
}
```

Your presenter can then call the `OpenSettings()` method. The method would be implemented by a concrete view class and might look like this:

```
public class MainView : UserControl, IMainView
{
    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        var settingsView = viewLoader.Load(typeof(settingsView));
        this.tabControl.add(settingsView);
    }
}
```

Notice the actual concrete view that implements the interface can use the `ViewLoader` to load the view so it only has to concern itself with inserting the view into the view hierarchy (because the `ViewLoader` has provided a fully configured view).

Notice also that the `IMainView` interface describes the application behaviour and not the actual implementation (i.e. it is named `OpenSettings` rather than `OpenDialog`). This means that if the view changes the way it opens the settings view (such as displaying it in a dialog box) then only the view needs to be updated; the presenter does not need to be changed at all as it will still call the `OpenSettings()` method to invoke the desired behaviour.

In summary:

- The presenter calls a method on the view to drive the behaviour.
- The view is hidden behind an interface to hide details of the view technology.
- The view loader is responsible for loading views and wiring them up to their models and presenters.
- The view asks the view loader to load the required view and is responsible for displaying the returned, fully configured view.